# Execute shell command on IR input on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, remote-control, infrared, lirc

I'm a Unix n00b, but I managed to follow enough guides to install node.js and node-sonos-http-api which allows me to do localhost/livingroom/play to start the music

I have a Nwazet Pi Infrared Receiver and now I want to control Sonos with my TV remote.

I was thinking that I could somehow listen for incoming IR with LIRC and then just e.g. 'curl localhost/livingroom/play' based on what was pressed.

Any idea how to do this and where to start?

Answer (score 1):

1. Configured my remote by finding the right .conf file here
   http://lirc.sourceforge.net/remotes/
2. Configured irexec by editing the lircrc config file
   http://www.lirc.org/html/configure.html
3. Ran irexec asa deamon 
   http://www.lirc.org/html/irexec.html